# Youtube Data API v3 - Able to fetch page results only for limited number of pages

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am making use of the Search.List method from YouTube Data API v3 and doing a keyword search with maxResults=50 per page. The totalResults has a value more than 13000 and I am able to send the nextPageToken from the second query and fetch the subsequent page results. But beyond 10-12 pages I do not get the nextPageToken parameter in my response at all.(Since the totalResults is more than 13000, I should atleast get around 260 pages.)

How do I get page results for the remaining pages? Is this something to do with the quota?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500231/how-can-get-all-results-from-youtube-api-search-api-response