# Youtube API v3 return only 19 NextPageToken for any request

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I trying use youtube API for get 80k videos id's, but youtube API return only first 19 pages, after `NextPageToken == undefined`, I tried use other request with other keywords and have same problem.

```
async.eachSeries(check_array, function iterator(value, callback) {
            console.log(next_page);

            var params = {
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: max,
                order: 'title'

            }

            if(next_page){
                params.pageToken = next_page;
            }

            client.search(params, function (err, data) {
                //console.log(data);
                if (err) throw err;

                if(data.nextPageToken === "undefined"){

                    console.log('Its end');

                }else{
                    next_page = data.nextPageToken;
                     data.items.forEach(function (value, index) {
                         connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO videos (video_id,uploaded) VALUES ("'+value.id.videoId+'",false)',
                             function (error, results, fields) {
                                if (error) throw error;
                            });
                     });

                    callback();
                }


            });
        });
```

Comment: i guess youtube wants to prevent that someone grills their servers.

Comment: It's a weird because youtube have a 1,000,000 points for the API, one request cost 100 points, probably I can parse 500,000 videos, because one request = 50 videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube soft limit for searches is 500 videos, regardless of total results.

See [How can get all results from Youtube API (search API) response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500231/how-can-get-all-results-from-youtube-api-search-api-response/27526563#27526563)