# 500 Video YouTube API Cap

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a full list of YouTube videos a channel has. I specifically need:

- videoId
- title
- publishedAt
- viewCount

I'm trying to doing this through YouTube's data API in a PHP script.

Currently, my query looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&key=' . $key . '&channelId=' . $channelId . '&order=date&maxResults=50&pageToken=' . $nextPageToken
```

It returns 50 results, and if there are more, it provides a nextPageToken that I use in a loop.

Unfortunately, it stops at 500 results and doesn't provide a viewCount. It also provides a lot of extra information which I don't need.

Is there a way I can accomplish my goals? I imagine they would support it in an API because all of this information is publicly accessible through the website, but scrapping it there would be poor form.

Comment: possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500231/how-can-get-all-results-from-youtube-api-search-api-response/27526563](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500231/how-can-get-all-results-from-youtube-api-search-api-response/27526563), your answer to the query is in the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get all results from Youtube API (search API) response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500231/how-can-get-all-results-from-youtube-api-search-api-response)