# https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search api returning empty response

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to search videos through `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/` api.

When I call the api for the first time without pageToken, i am getting pageInfo - totalResults as 1000000.

After loading more than 500 in my recyclerview, loadafter not getting called because search API returning empty items.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. 1

Answer (score 1):

YouTube Search call has a soft limit of 500 results returned, regardless of total found.

See this answer how to get all: [How can get all results from Youtube API (search API) response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500231/how-can-get-all-results-from-youtube-api-search-api-response/27526563#27526563)